# Application Settings with Mono under Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, application-settings

To store application settings, I am using the Settings tab in the project properties. In the code, I write `Settings.Default.FontSize = size;` and then `Settings.Default.Save();`
When I close the application and run it again the new value of the setting should be there. And yes, it is working properly on Windows, with Mono 2.4 on Windows, but NOT working with Mono 2.4 on Linux. It is not saving anything under Linux.

Have you got any clues?

Regards,
Petar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that Mono stores the user settings in ~/.local/share/. There were already settings there(without me knowing) of a different version of the program. I just deleted the folder and Mono saved the new one. Everything worked fine:)